# How to extract last two word using split() in python?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the data which needs to be extracted:

[image]

I tried this code to extract last two words

```
(missing_migrants["Place of Information"]
=missing_migrants["Location Description"].str.split[-2:])
```

but it resulted to an error

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-0de415609b6e> in <module>
----> 1 missing_migrants["Place of Information"]=missing_migrants["Location Description"].str.split().str.get[-2:]

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Where am I doing error? Please help. The column from which it needs to be extracted is shared as an image.

Comment: Use `missing_migrants["Location Description"].str.split().str[-2:]`

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-06c871e8bdc5> in <module>
----> 1 missing_migrants["Location Description"].str.split.str[-2:]

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Try again, there ws something wrong

Comment: Got it yatu...Thanks for your help

Comment: interesting dataset, try not to share images as no one can really reproduce that with the manual effort of typing your dataset out word by word. just paste in the first 10 rows or so so people can copy into editors . [ask] & [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str[-2]` for indexing last 2 words:

```
missing_migrants = pd.DataFrame({'Location Description':['aa bb cc','d dd','ff gg hh ii']})

missing_migrants["Place of Information"] = (missing_migrants["Location Description"]
                                                     .str.split()
                                                     .str[-2:])
print (missing_migrants)
  Location Description Place of Information
0             aa bb cc             [bb, cc]
1                 d dd              [d, dd]
2          ff gg hh ii             [hh, ii]
```

If want last values in strings add [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
missing_migrants["Place of Information"] = (missing_migrants["Location Description"]
                                                     .str.split()
                                                     .str[-2:]
                                                     .str.join(' '))
print (missing_migrants)
  Location Description Place of Information
0             aa bb cc                bb cc
1                 d dd                 d dd
2          ff gg hh ii                hh ii
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to get docstring in python for "str "?. I tried help() and '?' but there was no result

Comment: @ShripadKumar - documentation is same like indexing strings, check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#indexing-with-str)

Comment: Love the str.join addition. This is very useful for unfashionable columns that get converted into lists in data frames using the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

As @jezrael mention, the code you need is:

```py
missing_migrants["Place of Information"]=missing_migrants["Location Description"].str.split().str[-2:]
print (missing_migrants)
```

The error you were receiving was because you were missing the `()` after `split`. If you read the error message it says *TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable*. This indicates that you trying to call `str[-2:]` on the `split` method *itself* instead of the *result* of the method call.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to get docstring in python for "str "?. I tried help() and '?' but there was no result